# What does it mean for an ETF to have outflow, doesn't every every sell have a corresponding buy?

Tags: etf, markets

I often read something along the lines that some ETF has big outflow. I never quite understand what this means since it's exchange traded: doesn't every sell have a corresponding buy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every sell has a corresponding buy, but if the buyer is a market maker for the ETF and they accumulate significant amount of shares for which the market has no other buyers - they'll be redeemed from the fund and the fund will need to sell some of its assets.

Also, see [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22081/how-can-i-know-if-the-etf-stock-is-bought-by-stock-participant-change-or-the-f?rq=1) and its answers.